# Is Adobe creative cloud membership required for Xd - Jira integration?

Tags: creative-cloud, adobe-xd, plugin

Is creative cloud account is required to integrate Adobe Xd with Jira? There is no free way doing that?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, to use *any* Adobe app (beyond the 30 day trial period) a subscription is required.

Comment: The iOS app appears to be freeware but with 'in-app purchases'. I didn't investigate what those were. The desktop app is £10 a month, similar to any other Adobe rental.

Comment: @Scott Well, almost any – Acrobat Reader (or whatever it is it’s called these days) doesn’t require a subscription and some of the mobile apps, like Photoshop Express, don’t either. Unless I’m misremembering, Xd also didn’t when it first came out, but it does now.